# iOS: How to load a xib inside framework

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, xib

I created a new Framework containing a xib view using CocoaPod, and a test application to test that framework. The test application contains one button that makes a call to that framework and to show the xib.

At first I had a crash inside the framework at this line:

```
if let myView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("myCustomXib", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? myCustomXibClass
```

The log: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/User/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F7B870D5-4CEC-4CC7-9C76-75DF1408A26C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/20E3D273-315C-43EE-95CC-9B00B8EE8B6E/appDemo.app> (loaded)' with name 'myCustomXib''`

Then I changed that line with this:

```
let bundle = Bundle(identifier:"com.framework.identifier")

    if let myView = bundle?.loadNibNamed("myCustomXib", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? myCustomXibClass {
```

and the crash is gone, but nothing is displaying.

here is how I added the sources in my podspec:

```
  s.resources   = ["**/*.{storyboard,xib}", "Assets.xcassets"]
```

and I get all the files in my local development pod. The storyboards work perfectly, but not the xib. So how can I do ?

Comment: Anyone had this problem ?

Comment: Hi, You got the above solution.

Comment: It sounds that you run your code locally from a "Development Pods" directory, if so  use CMD+SHIFT+K to take effect

Answer (score 0):

Create a short static class, let's call it *MyFrameworkBundle*:

```
public final class MyFrameworkBundle {
    public static let main: Bundle = Bundle(for: MyFrameworkBundle.self)
}
```

And for a *XIB* in a *WindowController*:

```
public class MyFrameworkWindowController: NSWindowController {

    override public var windowNibName: String! {
        return "MyFrameworkWindowController"
    }

    public init() {
        super.init(window: nil) 

        /* Load window from xib file */
        MyFrameworkBundle.main.loadNibNamed(windowNibName, owner: self, topLevelObjects: nil)
    }

    // Override this as required per the class spec
    required public init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented. Use init()")
    }

    override public func awakeFromNib() {
        //Do your stuff
    }
}
```

If you run your code locally from a "**Development Pods**" directory, use `CMD+SHIFT+K` before running first time.