# my custom framework crashing 'Could not load NIB in bundle

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, xib, nib

I  have a custom framework which includes one xib and a UIView class for the same.

when I connect my test app with the framework, it got crashed

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/10A66571-E4BA-4C82-BDCE-82DA8018CA1C/cam.app> (loaded)' with name 'scanner''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1b318bab0 0x1b2ea5028 0x1b307b2fc 0x1b6efbb4c 0x1b6efc9e4 0x104902338 0x104901e68 0x104902078 0x1048a7c60 0x1048a74d8 0x1048a740c 0x1048a7514 0x1b6c29994 0x1b6c2e5c8 0x1b6c2e9b4 0x1b72a9c58 0x1b72a9354 0x1b72aa2f0 0x1b72bb4d4 0x1b74ab924 0x1b68729ac 0x1b726d370 0x1b726d700 0x1b6e08dec 0x1b8355ec0 0x1b837cb50 0x1b8360fa4 0x1b837c7e4 0x104cab27c 0x104cae9a4 0x1b83a3304 0x1b83a2fb0 0x1b83a351c 0x1b310724c 0x1b31071a0 0x1b310695c 0x1b31017d8 0x1b3101084 0x1bd34f534 0x1b7271670 0x1048a867c 0x1b2f80e18)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

my framework code

```
import UIKit
import QKMRZScanner
public class scanner: UIView,QKMRZScannerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var mrzScannerView: QKMRZScannerView!

    public func mrzScannerView(_ mrzScannerView: QKMRZScannerView, didFind scanResult: QKMRZScanResult) {
        print(scanResult.documentType)
    }

    override  init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commitinit()
        mrzScannerView.delegate = self
    }


    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func commitinit(){
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("scanner", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(mrzScannerView)
        mrzScannerView.frame = self.bounds
        mrzScannerView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    }

    public func capture(){
        mrzScannerView.startScanning()
    }


}
```

my test app code below

```
import UIKit

import testfrme
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tt: scanner!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let d = scanner()
        d.capture()

    }


}
```

can anyone help me to understand why its crashing ??
full source code of both available here
[testapp code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0xzkdlej51kv8xq/app.zip?dl=0)
[framework code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/strcy5vjosv7ajz/sdk.zip?dl=0)

**updated:**

new crash screenshot 
[image]

**UPDATED :**

When i tried

```
        mrzScannerView = Bundle(for: QKMRZScannerView.self).loadNibNamed("QKMRZScannerView", owner: self, options: nil)
```

am getting below error
[!enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESbhE.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESbhE.png)

My xib connections look like this
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Make sure, that your scanner views Nib is exactly called "scanner".
Don't set your nibs TopView to type "scanner". Instead set filesOwner to "scanner".
Add a subview to your nib, set this views class to "QKMRZScannerView".
Connect this view to your `@IBOutlet var mrzScannerView`

Load your views nib like this:

```
func commitinit() {  
    let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: self), bundle: Bundle(for: type(of: self))) 

    guard let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView else {
        fatalError("Failed to instantiate nib \(nib)")
    }
    self.addSubview(view)
    view.frame = self.bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I missunderstood your problem. I'll update my answer

Comment: You were correct before,  bcoz they are providing one framework without UI, so i want to create a wrapper on top of it by adding a ui also. So when i call the method including ui everything will be present. While creating new framework am facing above issues

Comment: if i remove my commitinit () then it will crash https://pasteboard.co/IUa9VQKp.png

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'scanner' to expected argument type 'AnyClass' (aka 'AnyObject.Type')

Comment: my uiview class is still QKMRZScannerView and Mocule is QKMRZView.  FileOwner class is "scanner"

Comment: view.frame = self.bounds . like this ryt

Comment: I dont know why this crashing again , screenshot https://pasteboard.co/IUagDUo.png

Comment: its same crash, like above screenshot link

Comment: oh I see.. you need to call your commitinit() method. my suggestion to remove this was related to misunderstanding of your setup

Comment: yeah, correct. my bad. i added that commit call. But its again crashed . Am attaching updated Xib connects and code screenshot along with crash here . https://pasteboard.co/IUaooVK.png          https://pasteboard.co/IUaoBlC.png        https://pasteboard.co/IUaoQIr.png    https://pasteboard.co/IUap6ew.png

Comment: The screenshot shows, that you still have set the nibs top views class to `QKMRZScannerView`. Please set class to UIView and add "QKMRZScannerView" as a subview in your nib

Comment: ok, can u check this once, i have updated correctly but crashing in different place https://pasteboard.co/IUay9fM.png   https://pasteboard.co/IUayzyp.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207582/discussion-between-naveen-kumar-and-robin-schmidt).

Comment: Still it crashing any idea?

Comment: will this works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51880281/ios-how-to-load-a-xib-inside-framework???

Answer (score 0):

in your commitinit func add these codes

```
let bundle = Bundle(identifier:"your Bundle ID") 
bundle?.loadNibNamed("your XIB file name", owner: self,options: nil)
```