# Framework within framework is getting crashed when loading xib swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, frameworks

I have added a UI xib to 3rd party frameworks and made a new one out of it called F3.framework, now i added a wrapper framework over F3 and made new framework all together called F4.

My app is connected to F4 and from F4 am calling F3 and inside F3 i have one xib and few other 3rd party framework.

I connected my app and F3 then its working fine, but when i introduced F4 its started crashing saying  ** Auto link error with other framework i used to build F4.frameworks**

then i moved my app viewcontroller codes to F4.framework now app getting crashed

```
Unknown class _TtC12QKMRZScanner7scanner in Interface Builder file
```

This is how i calling from my app

```
import F4
```

When i click to open my xib inside framework through button click

```
 @IBAction func capture(_ sender: Any) {
        let pla = F4()
        let c =  pla.load()
        pla.startCapture()
        self.view.addSubview(c)

    }
```

Now in my F4.framework code have only one file inside that

```
import Documents
```

```
public class F4 : ScanProtocol{

    var d: scanner!  //scanner is a UIView class in F3.framework

    public func scanResult(dictResult: [String : Any]) {
        print(dictResult)
    }

      let document = Documents()

     public init(){
      print("loading")
    }

    public func startCapturingPassport(){

        document.captureFromDocument() 
    }

    public func loadScanner() -> scanner{
        d = UINib(nibName: "scanner", bundle: Bundle(for: scanner.self)).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! scanner
        d.delegate = self
    return d
    }
```

Now in F3.framework am using following code

```
public class F3 {


    /// #TODO
    public init(){

    }



    /// CaptureMRZCodeFromDocument will call when user click on MRZ option and it will return the MRZ value

    public func captureFromDocument(){
       let mrz = scanner()
        mrz.capture()
    }
```

From F3.framework it will call capture() in scanner.swift like below

```
import QKMRZScanner
import QKMRZParser

public protocol ScanProtocol{
    func scanResult(dictResult : [String : Any])
}

public class scanner: UIView,QKMRZScannerViewDelegate {

    public var delegate: ScanProtocol?
    var mrzScannerView: QKMRZScannerView!
    var validatedMRZData: Dictionary<String, Any>!

public func mrzScannerView(_ mrzScannerView: QKMRZScannerView, didFind scanResult: QKMRZScanResult) {
    //Validate the data
    let scanValidation = ScannerValidation()
    validatedMRZData = scanValidation.ValidateMRZData(result: scanResult)
    delegate?.scanResult(dictResult: validatedMRZData)
}



override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    mrzScannerView = QKMRZScannerView(frame: self.bounds)
    mrzScannerView.delegate = self
    addSubview(mrzScannerView)
    mrzScannerView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    mrzScannerView = QKMRZScannerView(frame: self.bounds)
    mrzScannerView.delegate = self
    addSubview(mrzScannerView)
    mrzScannerView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
}

private func commitinit(){
    mrzScannerView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("scanner", owner: self, options: nil) as? QKMRZScannerView
    addSubview(mrzScannerView)
    mrzScannerView.frame = self.bounds
    mrzScannerView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
}

public func capture(){
    mrzScannerView.delegate = self

    mrzScannerView.startScanning()
}
```

This is the CRASH am getting now

```
2020-02-13 21:39:48.955020+0530 MRZ[32832:608471] [Storyboard] Unknown class _TtC12QKMRZScanner7scanner in Interface Builder file.
2020-02-13 21:39:48.955585+0530 MRZ[32832:608471] [Storyboard] Unknown class _TtC12QKMRZScanner16QKMRZScannerView in Interface Builder file.
Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x1d620e4b8) to 'F3.scanner' (0x1050fd998).
2020-02-13 21:39:48.957236+0530 MRZ[32832:608471] Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x1d620e4b8) to 'F3.scanner' (0x1050fd998).
```

Comment: How are you adding your frameworks to your project ?

Comment: Add files, and added in embed framework and made it as embed without sign

Comment: Did you set you scanner view in your storyboard to `QKMRZScannerView` ?

Comment: i set my scanner.xib class as scanner , and inside view as QKMRZScannerView, Module as QKMRZScanner

Comment: You already asked a very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60164479/my-custom-framework-crashing-could-not-load-nib-in-bundle  Please do not repost questions.

Comment: its not similar and both are entirely different, only modules are same